# F#: Reduce a list of tuples by grouping one of the elements into arrays

Tags: arrays, list, f#, tuples

I have a list of tuples which i want to group by one of its elements as a key. For example, if i had this list of tuples:

> [(A, "hello"), (A, "stack"), (A,"over"), (A, "flow"), (B, "how"), (B,
>   "you"), (C, "doin")]

I would like to get a result in the form:

> [(A, ["hello", "stack", "over", "flow"]), (B, ["how", "you"]), (C,
>   ["doin"])]

I am new to F# so I am all out of ideas on how to do this. I thank you in advance.

cheers

Comment: See the comments here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354684/order-a-list-in-f#comment39531968_25354684

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using incorrect delimiter for list elements - instead of `,` you need to use `;`.

To get results use this snippet:

```
[("A", "hello"); ("A", "stack"); ("A","over"); ("A", "flow"); ("B", "how"); ("B", "you"); ("C", "doin")]
  |> Seq.groupBy fst 
  |> Seq.map (fun (key,groupping) -> key, (groupping |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList)) 
  |> Seq.toList
```