# F#: Expand a list of tuples of form (string*string list) list using a key

Tags: list, f#, tuples

The other day I asked how could reduce a list of tuples by grouping one of the elements into arrays ([F#: Reduce a list of tuples by grouping one of the elements into arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395075/f-reduce-a-list-of-tuples-by-grouping-one-of-the-elements-into-arrays)). I wish now to learn how to do the opposite of this. Lets say I have this:

> ("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"])

and I want to get this:

> [("A", "B") ; ("A", "C") ; ("A" , "D") ; ("A" , "E")]

What is the functional way to do this? How could I do it with a list of elements of this type to be appended? I have tried:

> let prb = ("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"]) |> [for i in snd -> (fst, i)]

But hasn't worked.

Thanks a lot for your answers! I am new to F# and I am sorry if this is really basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `List.map` on `snd source`:

```
let source = ("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"]);;

// val source : string * string list = ("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"])

let result = snd source |> List.map (fun x -> fst source, x);;

// val result : (string * string) list =
//    [("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("A", "E")]
```

**Update**

For list of these elements

```
let source = [("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"]);("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"]);("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"])];;

// val source : (string * string list) list =
//   [("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"]); ("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"]);
//    ("A", ["B"; "C"; "D"; "E"])]
```

you can declare a function with code from above

```
let collectTuple (x, items) = items |> List.map (fun y -> x, y);;

// val collectTuple : x:'a * items:'b list -> ('a * 'b) list
```

and use it to call `List.map`:

```
let result = source |> List.map collectTuple;;

// val result : (string * string) list list =
//   [[("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("A", "E")];
//    [("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("A", "E")];
//    [("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("A", "E")]]
```

or `List.collect` if you want just one list of tuples instead:

```
let result = source |> List.collect collectTuple;;

// val result : (string * string) list =
//   [("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("A", "E"); ("A", "B"); ("A", "C");
//    ("A", "D"); ("A", "E"); ("A", "B"); ("A", "C"); ("A", "D"); ("A", "E")]
```

Comment: Although, how could I do this for a list of this elements?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `List.map`, you can also use list comprehensions. For simple transformations, this is usually my preferred option, but this is really just a matter of style, so Marcin's answer is perfectly fine.

The finished version looks like this:

```
let collectTuple (key, values) = 
  [ for v in values -> key, v ]
```

In your attempted solution, you tried to use `fst` and `snd` to access the elements of the tuple, which works too:

```
let collectTuple input = 
  [ for v in snd input -> fst input, v ]
```

Comment: Would there be a performance difference between our solutions?